# Visual Studio project dependency

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation

My background is in Java, and I will start working on a project written in Visual C++.
This Visual C++ project is dependent on several other internal and external projects. Most of them are internal company's projects and exist on my organisations internal Git repository.

And some of them, while external projects, also exist in the organisations's internal Git repository (MySQL, boost etc.).

The current practice is that before compiling the project locally, a prebuild.bat is run. That file has entries like below for **all dependencies** projects:

`rd /s /q "C:\DependenciesLibraries\CompanyLogger\"
MKDIR "C:\DependenciesLibraries\CompanyLogger\"
CD "C:\DependenciesLibraries\CompanyLogger\"
git init
git remote add origin http://myusername@gitlab.example.com/Utils/CompanyLogger.git
git fetch
git checkout origin/Features -- Debug/
git checkout origin/Features -- Release/
git checkout origin/Features -- CompanyLogger/CompanyLogger.h`

Then, when building, all these fetched repositories are also build. While it works, I am sure it has to be a better practice for this, that needs less effort and time to manage these dependencies. What are the best practices and other options that I have to manage internal and external dependencies when doing a local compile?

Comment: `other options .. to manage internal and external dependencies`: nuget